# JQM: Dynamic List not displayng JQM style, tried several fixes to no avail

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have tried a ton of solutions and am in the hair pulling stage, if anyone can help it would be deeply appreciated... TIA. :)

I am attempting to display the contents of a JSON array in my HTML with proper styling in place. Here is the JSON array I am loading:
http://highendwholesale.com/json.php

Here is the result I get when using the code below, as you can see it loads fine but without styling -- if anyone can help me get this working I would be grateful:
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON("json.php", function(data){
        $('ul#myInventory').empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, d){           
            $('ul#myInventory').append("<li><a href='#'><img src='http://highendwholesale.com/listings/"+d.CID+"/thumb/1.jpg' height='80' width='80' alt='"+d.CID+"' /><h2>"+d.title+"</h2><p>"+d.blurb+"</p></a></li>");
        });         
        $('ul#myInventory').trigger("create");          
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("error occurred!");
    });
    $('ul#myInventory').listview('refresh');         
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="d">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Inventory</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <div id="inventory">
        <ul data-role='listview' id='myInventory' data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'></ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('[data-role=listview]').listview().listview('refresh');` is all you need to add after appending the items (outside the loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare ul in your html first. Then appen li to this ul. 
Add this after your ajax call for listview.

```
$('ul#yourList').trigger("create");
```

## UPDATE HTML

```
<div data-role="content">   
    <div id="inventory">
        <ul data-role='listview' id='myInventory' data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'></ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

## UPDATE JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON("json.php", function(data){
        $('ul#myInventory').empty();

        $.each(data, function(index, d){           
        $('ul#myInventory').append('<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn-up-c">'+
            '<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">'+
                '<div class="ui-btn-text">'+
                    '<a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">'+
                        '<img src="http://highendwholesale.com/listings/'+d.CID+'/thumb/1.jpg" height="80" width="80" alt="'+d.CID+'" class="ui-li-thumb">'+
                        '<h2 class="ui-li-heading">'+d.title+'</h2>'+
                        '<p class="ui-li-desc">'+d.blurb+'</p>'+
                    '</a>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</li>');
    });

        $('ul#myInventory').trigger("create");          
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("error occurred!");
    });
    $('ul#myInventory').listview('refresh');         
});
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the help however that isn't working, i.e. I posted your code here:
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

Same issue still occurs. I'm at wit's end.

Comment: I updated my answer and try again with this, $('ul#inventory').trigger("create");

Comment: Hi, deeply appreciated -- I updated the code in my original post up top to reflect what I have there now -- even with your latest code added it's not working -- but this latest code changed the text color for some reason, i.e. see here:
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

Those are both fixes I had tried prior to posting based upon forum search, thanks for posting the code here for me, deeply appreciated.

Comment: ok, now try to add in again this $('ul#inventory').listview('refresh'); after the line $('ul#inventory').trigger("create");

Comment: Thank you. I added that code (I changed the ul id to myInventory to avoid conflict with the list content div), still not working although the text stays the new color, see here:
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

I updated the code in the original post to show the latest code

Comment: ? check this one also. [role="listview"]. You aldy added <div id="inventory" role="listview"></div> in your html. And you add again with script html.push("<ul data-role='listview' id='inventory' data-inset='true'>"); ... just leave <div id="inventory"></div> and try again.

Comment: OK I deleted the lisview role from the div, still not working, see here:

Comment: no, i mean role="listview" from your DIV. Bcoz, you aldy had data-role='listview' in your ul, right.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the role listview from the div, still not working. I updated the code above in the original code to the latest code, see result here:
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

Comment: not sure what we missed out here... check my update code again. Add class for ul in script. 

html.push("<ul data-role='listview' id='myInventory' data-inset='true' class='ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow'>");

Comment: Thank you yeyene. That did improve it, but not fix it, see here result
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

Comment: Ohh!! I found the error, you used comma ( , ) in your js script to join, instead of plus sign ( + ), check my update answer again.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your continued help here, desperate to fix this -- I changed the code as per your advice, updated code above to latest code. Still not working though, see here:
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

Comment: Okie, I will update my answer as my working scripts, copy and try again. My script use .append() function. And also add ul in html code, not by script.

Comment: If there is an easier way to do it I would happily change the code, whatever works. Again, thank you yeyene. You are a hero tonight.

Comment: Thanks. I updated code above so show how I added your changes, still not working, see here:
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

Comment: I have no idea, last change, try my update jquery for appending part. That's how exactly jquery would apply listview style to html code.

Comment: THAT DID IT! My god, I am so grateful to you yeyene. I can't thank you enough... Peace brother. You are the man.

Comment: wow! yess, one more, you add data-corners="false" to li append, check my update answer. You owe me a green tick, bro if you accept my answer.

Comment: Sorry one final issue, the rounding with that code on the bottom of each button is off, any idea how to tweak that? See here:
http://highendwholesale.com/test.php

Comment: check my update answer, $('ul#myInventory').append('<li data-corners="false" ...>);

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you yeyene. Green check mark done, if I had rep here I would vote you up too. Cheers man.